# How do automount permissions work

Tags: permission, mount, automount

I have an automount set up in a file `/etc/auto_synology` which is referenced by `/etc/automaster` which looks like this:

```
Media -fstype=afp afp://[USER]:[PASSWORD]@jDiskStation.local/Media
Downloads -fstype=afp afp://[USER]:[PASSWORD]@jDiskStation.local/downloads
```

These are mounted in `/mnt/synology/[Media|Downloads]`

When I mount these via:

```
sudo automount -vc
```

It is successful and I can access the directories ok.

## Denied Access on Reconnect

If I disconnect my laptop from the network and reconnect, the automounts appear mounted but I get permission denied.

```
mount -f
```

yields:

```
map auto_synology on /mnt/synology (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
```

Also, working permissions on the directory looks like this:

```
dr-xr-xr-x  4 root   wheel    3  3 Dec 20:39 ./
drwxr-xr-x  4 james  wheel  128 18 Nov 15:19 ../
drwx------  1 james  wheel  264  3 Dec 20:34 Downloads/
drwx------  1 james  wheel  264  3 Dec 20:14 Media/
```

Comment: Does https://superuser.com/questions/997735/how-to-mount-smb-share-that-can-be-accessed-by-anyone-on-mac-os-x-el-capitan help?

Comment: What do you mean by "disconnect my laptop"? Is this a software disconnect or a hardware one?

Comment: @danielAzuelos - hardware. Leave my home network physically

Comment: There is no way to avoid damage in such a case: it depends on the network activity about your actual active mounted file systems, and due to caches you can't sync pending operations (for example the access time of a directory because you click on it in the FInder) any other way than through a software disconnect or a clean unmount.